# trying to print data from streambuilder to textview on flutter

Tags: flutter

I already have the value here but the problem

```
   return StreamBuilder(
        stream: widget.database.bonusStream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final bonusData = snapshot.data;
          print("here's the data${bonusData}");
          return ThemeSwitchingArea(
            child: Builder(
              builder: (
                context, {
                Bonus bonusData,
              }) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 3), //peletakan overall
                      header,
                      Flexible(
                        child: ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: kSpacingUnit.w *
                                  3), //untuk kecilin space disekitarnya really usefull
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ProfileListItem(
                              icon: LineAwesomeIcons.address_card,
                              text: '194K67D2',
                              hasNavigation: false,
                            ),
                            ProfileListItem(
                              icon: LineAwesomeIcons.truck,
                              text: 'Dump Truck',
                              hasNavigation: false,
                            ),
                            ProfileListItem(
                              icon: LineAwesomeIcons.money_bill,
                              text: "12000", //"${bonusData.bonus}",
                              hasNavigation: false,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
```

So on the streambuilder part, I try to print the snapshot.data and what I got [the instance of bonus],which is what I want, but the problem is, I want to try to view it in textview on the profilelist item below this part:

```
   
                            ProfileListItem(
                              icon: LineAwesomeIcons.money_bill,
                              text: "12000", //"${bonusData.bonus}",
                              hasNavigation: false,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

but what I get is a null, even though I already got the data when I try to print it begore getting to the "return themeswtichingarea".

Answer (score 0):

```
 builder: (
                context, {
                Bonus bonusData,
              })
```

conflicting with "bonusData" you change the same name.

Comment: in proflieListItem bonusData found null because first bonusData data not called here

Comment: im sorry i dont quite catch it, so how can i bring the instance from the streambuilder into the ProfileListitem?